# Can somebody give me an example of when it would make sense to have a member template of a class template?

Tags: c++, templates

I'm reading about how a class template may itself have a member function that is a template function, but the example of the book is not making it clear as to why this would ever be necessary. If it's already a class template, I would think any functions in it that need to use generic types would already be able to use them without the function needing to be defined itself as a template function...If that makes sense?

Comment: See e.g. the range [`std::vector::insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/insert)

Comment: See also contructor (8) for shared_ptr : (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) . This allows one to construct a shared_ptr with template type T from a shared_ptr with a different template type, Y say.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example usage for templated member function inside templated class as a unified storage for a certain base class with custom key.

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void print() const= 0;
  virtual ~Base(){}
};

#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct Derived: Base
{
  T t;
  void print() const{ std::cout<< t<< '\n'; }
  Derived(T const &t): t(t){}
};

#include <map>
#include <memory>

template <typename K>
struct Collection
{
  std::map<K, std::unique_ptr<Base>> datum;

  template <typename T>
  void add(K const &key, T const &t)
  {
    datum.insert(std::make_pair(key, std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Derived<T>(t))));
  }
  void print(K const &key){ datum.at(key)-> print(); }
};

int main()
{
  Collection<int> c;
  c.add(0, 42);
  c.add(1, std::string("hi"));
  c.print(0);
  c.print(1);
}
```

Here, the class template parameter `K` for `Collection` is used as `std::map` key's type and the member function template `add` is used for selecting a derived class that can be constructed using member function template parameter `T`.

Comment: hmm..a little confusing because we've yet to deal with keys or maps or anything like that in class, or with derived classes, but...I  think I kinda see what's going on.. @nurettin

Comment: map is just there as a dictionary container so you can find data by key. Example: `data["hi"]= 0;` and later modify it `data["hi"]++;` I made the key customizable by providing template parameter `K`. Derived class is there to make the member function template `T` necessary.